# File to import not found or unreadable: compass watch cant run

Tags: ruby, sass

hello guys i kind of stuck to find the problem here.
i can not run compass watch i dont know why

i go  to gitbash to check my version:

my ruby version `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]`

my compass  version `Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)`

sass  version `Sass 3.4.23`

```
/*
    Error: File to import not found or unreadable: sass/layout/header.
           Load paths:
             Compass::SpriteImporter
             C:/xampp/htdocs/test/sass
             C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets
            on line 2 of C:/xampp/htdocs/test/sass/main.scss

    1: @import "compass";
    2: @import "sass/layout/header";
    3: @import "sass/layout/footer";
```

my main.scss on inside folder sass

```
@import "compass";
@import "sass/layout/header";
@import "sass/layout/footer";
```

and my config just like this

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "../"
css_dir = "assets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

please  help me to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

dumb me, just found out the porblem cause on my main.scss i include

```
@import "sass/layout/header";
```

it should only `@import "layout/header";`

my bad